# RestClient converts params hash to cookie

Tags: ruby, rest-client

I'm playing around with RestClient and haven't been able to find an answer to this. I create a `params` hash that I'm passing to RestClient like so:

```
params = {params:{param1:value1, param2:value2}}
```

then I call the URL like so

```
RestClient.get URL, params
```

What's weird is that when I ask the console for `params` again, it looks like this:

```
 {:cookie=>"AWSELB=E90D276B18ACB0E9CF92FC50E2D6A7806BFB19AFAAB5A8DCD361BDAC4D65213E9ABF6FB1F2A3D2A7E0460E3D884F55A9AA3239C8FE9A071CC3F4ACEA34AE7B78F81E643FB7; MAX-AGE=3600; PATH=/"}
```

What's going on here?